# Norms under Conjugation by Projection Opertaros

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

I was reading about equivalent forms of the Kadison Singer Problem, and while looking at the Feichtinger Conjecture, I came across the claim that, for a projection operator $P$ and a self-adjoint operator with zero diagonal $H$ in the space of bounded linear operators on $\ell_2$, the following were equivalent.

$$ -\epsilon P \preceq PHP \preceq \epsilon P$$
and
$$\|PHP\| \leq \epsilon \|H\|$$

where $\epsilon>0$ and $A\succ B$ if there exists $C$ such that $A-B = C^* C$.

I can't find a proof of this, through googling or my own knowledge of norms and positive operators. Could someone explain, or point me in the right direction?